# bash script, execute command line and keep going the next for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line, background-process, execute

Is it possible to run a command in a for loop without waiting for that command ended, while keeping going to the next iteration?

Because I have to send multi-files at the same time asap via many ssh connections, therefore I couldn't wait until the command ended one by one.

Maybe is it related to something like 'xterm' or 'gnome-terminal'?

Comment: execute the command in the background with & ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can execute the command in background by adding `&` at its end.

So the syntax looks like `programName [arguments] &` (at least for bourne compatible shells)

Comment: Thanks I found `(command1 && command2) &` or `(command1; command2) &` difference b/w && and ; is a conditional sequence